# How to decrypt files that are uploaded with the SSE-C method using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, encryption

How to decrypt files that are uploaded with the SSE-C method. I have uploaded the files using the encryption key which I generated. Below the PowerShell command, I used to upload.

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $s3Bucket -Folder $thisFolder -KeyPrefix $s3Path -ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod AES256 -ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey "MyGeneratedKey"
```

I was able to upload the file/folder successfully. I want to know how to decrypt the uploaded file and save it to my local.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You decrypt it on retrieval (ie. using `Read-S3Object`) by specifying the same encryption method and key identifier

Comment: Thanks, Mathias for your valuable response.